# Retrieve PubSub Schema from external IP address with API Key

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsublite

1. I have created a PubSub schema
2. I have created an API key with no restrictions
3. I wish to cURL/Get this schema from an address outside of GCP
4. I tried the below request but it's denied as per below

   me@J-5CG2200NLY:~/go/$ curl https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myprojetc199/schemas/pbschema_1?key=mylongkeyxxxxxxxxxxxx
   {
   "error": {
   "code": 403,
   "message": "User not authorized to perform this action.",
   "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
   }
   }
   How can I authenticate my request?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pub/Sub does not support the use of API keys as an authentication method (as noted in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/authentication)). API keys are used for quota attribution for requests. You would have to use one of the alternative authentication methods like [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) in order to retrieve the schema via a cURL/Get.

If you are logged in via `gcloud` on an account that has permission to get schemas, you can then get the access token:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

Now, you can use that access token in a curl command:

```
PROJECT=my-project
SCHEMA=my-schema
ACCESS_TOKEN=<token printed out above>
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -X GET  https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT/schemas/$SCHEMA
```